# python program to compare text file with tracks from a playlist database displays all tracks

Tags: python, sqlite

For an assignment I need to import playlist (text file) into a database (chinook.db). An example of this text file is:

Bohemian Rhapsody

You're

Thriller

However, there may be several tracks that start with the given keywords from the file. In that case, the application should display a small selection menu with the different alternatives (artist name + track name).

When I run my code and have entered a file name and playlist name, I get a list of all the songs in the database. After this you will be asked to make a choice (this step should actually only come later after the tracks have been filtered on the tracks or keywords that are in the text file). After giving the choice, I do get the desired list of songs that start with "You're".

What I've done so far is an if statement that when results > 1 asks which song to add if multiple keywords are found. However, it only displays these songs after I have filled in a choice once. I need to do something with results but I can't get it done. Been struggling for hours the past couple days.This is the code:

```
import sqlite3
import os

def import_playlist(file_name, playlist_name):
    # Connect to the Chinook database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("chinook.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
        print("Error: the file does not exist.")
        return

    # Check if a playlist with the same name already exists in the database
    c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM playlists WHERE Name=?", (playlist_name,))
    if c.fetchone()[0] > 0:
        print("Error: a playlist with the same name already exists in the database.")
        return

    # Create a new playlist in the database
    c.execute("INSERT INTO playlists (Name) VALUES (?)", (playlist_name,))
    playlist_id = c.lastrowid

    # Read tracks from the file
    with open(file_name, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            track_name = line.strip()

            # Find tracks that match the search keywords
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE Name LIKE ?", (track_name + "%",))
            results = c.fetchall()

            # Show the alternatives if multiple tracks are found
            if len(results) > 1:
                track_id = None
                while track_id is None:
                    print("Make a choice from the following tracks:")
                    for i, track in enumerate(results):
                        print("{}   {}   {}".format(i+1, track[1], track[2]))
                    choice = input("Your choice:")
                    if choice.isnumeric() and int(choice) <= len(results):
                        track_id = results[int(choice)-1][0]
                    else:
                        print("Invalid Input")
            elif len(results) == 1:
                track_id = results[0][0]
            else:
                continue

            # Add the selected track to the playlist
            c.execute("INSERT INTO playlist_track (PlaylistId, TrackId) VALUES (?, ?)", (playlist_id, track_id))

    # Save the changes and close the database connection
    conn.close()

    print("The playlist has been imported.")

file_name = input("Enter the name of the file:")
playlist_name = input("Enter the name of the playlist:")
import_playlist(file_name, playlist_name)
```

I dont want all those tracks and the first "You're choice" printen.. I want this outcome:
[DesiredOutcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsFZU.png)

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, you're getting more results than expected in the query after "# Find tracks that match the search keywords." Is that correct? This should work as written. Are there blank lines in the file you're reading in? Those would cause it to match everything. I'd recommend putting something like "print(len(track_name), track_name)" just before that comment to see what you're sending to the select statement.

Comment: So in hindsight, that may have not been the best place to put it. The 17 is from the "Bohemian Rhapsody" line. The value you wanted to see was printed at the top of the list of 3k songs. Anyhow, it sounds like blank lines are the problem. You'll want to check the length of the line and do a continue if it is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a blank (or white space only) line in the input file, the strip will reduce it to an empty string. The SQL query then reduces to "... WHERE LIKE "%" and matches every row. To resolve this check for an empty string and skip to the next line.

```py
for line in file:
    track_name = line.strip()
    if len(track_name) == 0:
        continue;

    # Find tracks that match the search keywords
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE Name LIKE ?", (track_name + "%",))
    results = c.fetchall()
```

Comment: This was the error, thanks for helping me out! You're the best. Regards